# Is there a way to use Foundry Model for Authentification inside Functional Tests?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

```
1) App\Tests\Controller\Admin\Api\Promotion\PromotionDeleteControllerTest::test_deleting_promotion
LogicException: The first argument of "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\KernelBrowser::loginUser" must be instance of "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface", "Zenstruck\Foundry\Proxy" provided.
```

I am writing functional test with phpunit library. I want to create admin object for testing with AdminFactory (extends Foundry ModelFactory) and then authenticate my API request using given object with built in Symfony method

```
$this->client->loginUser($admin, 'admin');
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found a solution myself. You have to do something like this:

```
AdminFactory::new()
    ->create([
        'email' => 'admin1@admin.com',
        'active' => true,
        'roles' => ['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'],
    ])
;

/** @var AdminRepository $adminRepository */
$adminRepository = static::getContainer()->get(AdminRepository::class);
$admin = $adminRepository->findOneBy(['email' => 'admin1@admin.com']);
```

This should return Entity instead of Foundry Proxy

Answer (score 0):

Just ask for the actual object:

```php
$admin = AdminFactory::AdminFactory::new()
    ->create([
        /* $attributes */
    ])
    ->object(); // retrieves the actual object
```

See [ZenstruckFoundryBundle Documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/ZenstruckFoundryBundle/current/index.html#object-proxy).